# Subgroup of order 24 in $S_7$?

Tags: group-theory

Is there a subgroup of order 24 in $S_7$? What can we do to answer this question?

Comment: Consider the subgroup of $S_7$ obtained by fixing 3 elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_7$.

Comment: Nice hint. It has more detail than what I was typing for a hint as this popped up.

Comment: you are right. i should have thought it.